# Android Espresso UI test - Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError'

Tags: java, android, exception, android-espresso, ui-testing

I faced with the following problem:

When i trying to start a stand-alone UI test using Espresso i always get the following console error message without the running the test.

```
Test running startedTest running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError'
Empty test suite.
```

So i tried to run command:

```
 gradle -q dependencies
```

And i obtained the following result:

```
androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
+--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.3
|    +--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.3
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1
+--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.3
|    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.3 (*)
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1 -> 2.2
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2
|    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.3 (*)
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
|    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
|    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.3 (*)
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2
|    \--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2
|    +--- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2
|    +--- com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework:accessibility-test-framework:2.0
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2 (*)
\--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1
```

I tried find the some solution on this topic, but without the luck.

[Tests fail after Espresso 2 upgrade (failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551989/tests-fail-after-espresso-2-upgrade-failed-instrumentation-run-failed-due-to)

I don't know what exactly I should to update to make test working.

Here is the app.gradle config file

```
   android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "test.my.app"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            // Enabling multidex support.
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }


    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
        compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.11'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
        // UI TESTING DEPENDENCIES
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
        //androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
        }
        // ORM DATABASE DEPENDENCIES
        compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        // STETHO CORE
        compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.1.1'
        compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-urlconnection:1.1.1'
        compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.1.1'
        // GOOGLE ANALYTICS
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
        // JODA TIME FOR ANDROID
        compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.2'
        // SECURE SHARED PREFERENCES
        compile 'com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.3'
        // MATERIAL DIALOG
        compile 'com.avast:android-styled-dialogs:2.2.0'
        // SQL CIPHER
        compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:sqlcipher-for-android:3.3.1'
        // HTML PARSER
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
        // MULTIDEX SUPPORT
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        // SECOND MATERIAL DIALOG
        compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.0.1@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        // ANDROID BOOTSTRAP
        compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.0.0'

    }
```

And Sample of TEST class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SignInActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SignInActivity> {

    public TestHelper tl = new TestHelper();
    public SignInActivityTest() {
        super(SignInActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        SignInActivity lActivity = getActivity();
    }

    // Insert scenario methods here
    @Test
    public void processTest() throws InterruptedException {

        // TODO: strings which are inserted into inputs should be defined as the string constants
        // Discuss it with Jan Sedlacek.
        tl.insertTextIntoInput(R.id.login_txv_username, "test");
        tl.insertTextIntoInput(R.id.login_txv_password, "test");
    }

}
```

What should i to change to make this working please? I will glad for any help.

Comment: did u manage to fix that? i'm running into the same issue. my test was actually extending AndroidTestCase instead.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same problem. Any solution on that?

Answer (score 1):

`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is deprecated you have to use `ActivityTestRule` instead:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SignInActivityTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SignInActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(SignInActivity.class);

    public TestHelper tl = new TestHelper();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //currently you don't use Activity instance in your tests
        //I just put it here as an example how to get the activity from ActivityTestRule
        SignInActivity lActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
    }

    // Insert scenario methods here
    @Test
    public void processTest() throws InterruptedException {
        tl.insertTextIntoInput(R.id.login_txv_username, "test");
        tl.insertTextIntoInput(R.id.login_txv_password, "test");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //do some stuff if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: oh man this is crazy, it's the second time in a row I stumble across an answer of yours in 2 days xD

Answer (score 1):

This is a Gradle bug with MultiDex, as discussed in [Android issue 194609](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194609):

> **m...@felixschulze.de:**
>   ... it seems that the dependency 'multidex' is added to the app itself and the androidTestCompile apk :(
>
> See: 
>   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-1.5/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/VariantManager.java#419
>
> ...
>
> Found a workaround, add this to your build.gradle file:

```
// Workaround for Multidex bug in gradle-android-plugin
// Replace Multidex dependency with some dummy dependency to avoid dex problems
// @see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194609
project.getConfigurations().all { config ->
    if (config.name.contains("AndroidTest")) {
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.name == "multidex") {
                details.useTarget("de.felixschulze.teamcity:teamcity-status-message-helper:1.2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, do not use MultiDexTestRunner.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem.

Mine was caused by an uncaught `InterruptedException` in some worker thread which stopped the testing process. The stacktrace shows up in the `Android Monitor`...I was able to solve my problem by catching the exception.

Answer (score -1):

This means that you have problem in Gradle file. You use wrong dependencies.

I use robotium and JUnit 4 my dependebcies:

```
 dependencies {
     androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'robotium-solo-5.5.4.jar')
     androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
     // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
     androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
 }
```